# frame size of detail view of splitviewcontroller does not change up in ios4.2

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, ios-4.2

I am implementing splitviewcontroller with two views master view and detail view in my ipad application. On changing the orientation of ipad from portrait to landscape I am need to hide the master view and change the detail view's frame size to show up on full screen. For this I am using this code.

```
    - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
       //adjust master view
       UIViewController *master = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
       UIViewController *detail = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
       CGRect t = master.view.frame;
       t.size.width = 0;
       t.size.height = 0;
       t.origin.x = 0;
       t.origin.y = 0;
       [master.view setHidden:YES];
       [master.view setFrame:t];

       //adjust detail view
       CGRect f = detail.view.frame;
       f.size.width = 1004;
       f.size.height = 768;
       f.origin.x = 0;
       f.origin.y = 0;

       [detail.view setFrame:f];

}
```

This code works exactly fine on ios3.2 but does not work for ios4.2. The master view gets hidden in ios4.2 but detail view's frame size does not change.

Please help me.
Thanks
Shruti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative that I found to my problem is that instead of hiding the master view and changing the frame size of detail view on rotation I just presented the class containing the detail view as the modal view. Earlier I was pushing it from the previous class. I also added a navigation bar to it with a done button to dismiss the modal view. This thing worked for me.

```
ListingViewController *viewController = [[ListingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListingViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];  
UINavigationController *modalVC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController]; // to add navigation bar
modalVC.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:modalVC animated:YES];
[modalVC release];
[viewController release];
```

Comment: This was just an alternative to what I did to resolve my problem. Its not exactly the answer to the asked question.